# Why do I lose time in datetime after .loc lookup in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: added the source dates:

```
2020-07-09 09:53:23.677

2020-07-20 12:00:01.134

2020-07-20 12:00:01.303

2020-07-20 12:00:01.632

2020-07-20 12:00:02.587
```

After loading a table I infer the datetime format:

```
TableA['updateddatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(TableA['updateddatetime'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors = 'coerce')
```

This looks right:

[image]

But once I do a `.loc` lookup

```
TableA_2 = TableA.loc[TableA['ID'] == 1234]
```

I lose the time:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you post the source data, `df_irss_historical['updateddatetime']`

Comment: Sorry - that is also TableA actually - just a type from translating it. I just corrected that. Would it still be helpful to see the source data?

Comment: yes, we want the data from `TableA` or at least the column in question

Comment: Ok - I just added it to the top

Comment: in text please...

Comment: A standalone reproducible example would really help here

Comment: Updated to text - And I will prepare a standalone reproducible example

Comment: What is the value of `TableA['ID']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the .loc lookup resulted in values where every time was 00:00:00.000. So pandas and/or jupyter abbreviated 12-11-01 00:00:00.000 to 12-11-01.